# Nginx proxy_no_cache and proxy_cache_bypass

Tags: caching, nginx

Here's the documentation:

> **proxy_cache_bypass**
> Defines conditions under which the response will not be taken from a cache. If at least one value of the string parameters is not empty and is not equal to “0” then the response will not be taken from the cache:
> `proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache$arg_comment;`
> `proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma    $http_authorization;`
> Can be used along with the proxy_no_cache directive.
>
> **proxy_no_cache**
> Defines conditions under which the response will not be saved to a cache. If at least one value of the string parameters is not empty and is not equal to “0” then the response will not be saved:
> `proxy_no_cache $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache$arg_comment;`
> `proxy_no_cache $http_pragma    $http_authorization;`
> Can be used along with the proxy_cache_bypass directive.

Does that mean if I want to totally exclude something in cache, I should set both `proxy_no_cache` and `proxy_cache_bypass`? Is it OK if I only set `proxy_cache_bypass`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes.

If you just have **proxy_cache_bypass** set true on pages you don't want cached (eg. logged in users) then they will still be saved into the cache and served to people who should get cached pages (eg. non logged in users).

But setting both **proxy_cache_bypass** and **proxy_no_cache** to true means that those users neither receive nor contribute to the cache.

Comment: Got caught by this one.  A lot of tutorials/examples only mention proxy_cache_bypass and not proxy_no_cache.  Wondered why visitors to the site were seeing it as if they were logged in.